# How do I take to trash a php document that I localizated wrong?

Tags: php

So I made a document through nano, but I located it in the wrong place. Now I was trying to remove it and I wasn't able to do it.
As I'm inexperient in code language (I'm learning) I though to ask what ways do you use or are the best to use to remove files in linux

Comment: Files are removed my `rm` command, moved to another location by `mv`.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!
Not that this question is likely better tagged with "linux" or "bash" than with "php".

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the file using the `rm` command, ex: `rm filename`.

If removal fails, the error itself might indicate why it failed.